# Searching a vector space (ish?)

Tags: vector-spaces, searching

I come from a computer science background so please forgive any math transgressions I make.

I will try to describe what I'm looking for as best as I can.

I've been looking into methods of searching a vector space for a "target" of sorts but I have no idea where to start.

A simple version is searching RGB space for a "colour" ( I'm assuming the cardinality here is 3 right?).
My idea is to present `p` number of options to a user. Each option is a different colour and they select the one closest to the colour they have in mind. Another set of options are presented closer to their target until they converge on the one they want.

I'm assuming that the `target` is itself a space since, in this case, the colours will become too similar for the user to tell apart. So as long as we end up in the `target space` we should be good.

So far, I think we have (again, feel free to correct me):

- Cardinality `c`
- Target space `t`
- Options presented `p`
- Number of options that need to be selected `n` to get to the target space

Now for my questions:

1. Is there a relationship between `c, t, p and n`?
2. Has any research been done into this sort of stuff and does it have a formal name?
3. For large value of `c`, I can image that values of `p` and `n` would also be quite large, but I'm assuming that I could reduce this by increasing `t`. Would this work?

Sorry again if this sounds like the ramblings of an idiot. Looking forward to any comments you have.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: How do you represent the input vector? For example, how do you represent the color you are searching for in the RGB space?

Comment: @JohnDouma If by input vector you mean one of the options the user selects then this would be (r,g,b) format so (128,0,128) for purple. This would be the same for any colour in the rgb space

Comment: Why wouldn't that be a constant time lookup? What is it about your search space that makes this non-trivial?

Comment: For RGB colors I would say that the *dimension* is $3,$ but the *cardinality* is often $256^3$.

Comment: That's a constant time search. You have a $256\times 256\times 256$ array that is indexed by RGB value.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yeah the RGB was just an example. What happens when the dimension ( thanks @md2perpe) is 20 or 30? There's is also the restriction that the user doesn't necessarily know the exact target, just that its more or less similar to a given example. A bit like a binary search

Comment: You should be more precise in your question. For example, what does it mean for two vectors to be similar?

Comment: @JohnDouma Yeah you're right. I think I should go away and think about this a little bit more then come back with a more specific example. Thank you for your time though